How to Upgrade from ERC-721 to ERC721A in a Web3 Project Using JSON ABI?
I am working on a Web3 project that allows users to customize NFTs through interchangeable traits. The project is built using Next.js for the frontend and wagmi for Web3 integration.
One of the challenges I am currently facing is upgrading my NFT contract from ERC-721 to ERC721A to improve gas efficiency for batch minting.
However, I only have the following:

The deployed contract address.
The contract's ABI in JSON format (built on ERC-721).

My Questions:
How can I upgrade or transition from ERC-721 to ERC721A without access to the original .sol files?
What is the best way to ensure compatibility with existing tokens and their metadata if redeployment is required?
Are there any tools or techniques that can facilitate this process while maintaining the current JSON ABI structure used for frontend integration?
I am open to writing a new contract using ERC721A if necessary, but I would appreciate guidance on how to handle this transition smoothly without affecting users.
Any tips, best practices, or resources for tackling this upgrade would be greatly appreciated!
I researched ways to upgrade the contract but most solutions require access to the original .sol files, which I don’t have. I expected to find a method to upgrade using only the ABI and contract address but couldn’t locate a clear process.


upgrading my NFT contract from ERC-721 to ERC721A

If the contract is already deployed and does not use a proxy pattern, it's immutable and not possible to change the code. You can, however, release a new contract (ERC721A) on a new address.
ABI (Application Binary Interface) is just an interface containing list of inputs and outputs to contract functions. But it doesn't hold any information about behavior of these functions (whether they run loops, increment numbers, etc).
